# C#におけるIDisposableインターフェース

Tags: c#, .net

WEB上で掲題の件について、多くの記事で議論されているのですが、以下の点だけ解決できなかったので、ご教示頂けますでしょうか。

`IDisposable`を実装したクラスの`Dispose`メソッドが呼ばれた後、当該クラスのインスタンス自体の参照はなくなるでしょうか。
例えば、以下の様なコードです。

```
private static sampleClass;

static void Main() {
    sampleClass = new SampleClass();
    sampleClass.Dispose();
}

public class SampleClass : IDisposable {
    private StreamReader reader;

    public SampleClass() {
        reader = new StreamReader();
    }

    public void Dispose() {
        reader.Dispose();
    }
}
```

`sampleClass` の参照はstatic変数に格納されてしまっている為、GC対象外になってしまうと思っています。`sampleClass`内の`reader`はGC対象の認識です。

認識に誤りがあるでしょうか。
よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`IDisposable.Dispose`自体は単なるメソッドですので、ガベージコレクションの参照追跡に関して特別な効果は持ちません。
ただし、デストラクターを実装している`IDisposable`実装型は`IDisposable.Dispose`の呼び出し時に時に`GC.SuppressFinalize`を実行してインスタンスをファイナライゼーションキューから削除することが推奨されています。

また`static`フィールドや今後使用されるローカル変数から参照されているインスタンスはGCの対象になりません。ですので質問の`SampleClass.reader`は`Program.sampleClass`から参照されていますので対象外です。